# Preg_replace syntax not working when used with whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am trying to use preg_replace on contents received from a file using file_get_contents

```
preg_replace("/\/\/data(.*?)\/\/enddata/i",$string,$contents);

$string = 'data new ';
```

// contents here with white spacing

```
$contents = '



//data
//enddata';
```

thing is preg_replace is getting executed but not updated :)

any ideas guys ? thnx

Answer (score 2):

Using /is helped with returning out the value after replace :)

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not match newlines unless you specifically tell it to by adding the `s` modifier.

Also, try using different delimiters. My personal preference is parentheses because they never need escaping, even if there are more parentheses inside the pattern :)

```
"(//data(.*?)//enddata)is"
```

Comment: He probably needs to assign the `preg_replace` return value to `$contents` also.

Comment: @user1690718. `preg_replace` won't actually change `$contents`.